# Kinect v2 compatible usb controller

Tags: kinect

I'm now trying to set up my kinect version 2

I installed Microsoft sdk and usb extension board (Renseas 720202)

Question is, Kinect can be detected before driver of usb board install.

In Kinect verifier program, usb controller are not compatible but can get

color image with low fps.

ahttp://ppt.cc/XvKOg   (Sorry I can't post more than two links. Plz remove 'a' and see the pic)

http://ppt.cc/kv38M

After install driver of usb board, I get nothing...

ahttp://ppt.cc/hbWAE

http://ppt.cc/Cw29u

I search that intel and Renaseas chips are compatible with Kinect v2.

What can I do? Thanks

#### update

In the end, I change computer which use intel chipset on mother board to solve the problem.

Comment: I'use another computer to solve the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846191/usb3-controller-kinect-2/30847224#30847224 helpful