# Issues with OpenNI - Kinect and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, point-cloud-library, openni, nite

I have spent the afternoon fiddling with a fresh ubuntu install, on a virtual machine (Running through vmware player on win 8) using an xbox kinect (360 version, designed for windows) trying to get OpenNI to work, (and plan on using pointcloud library with this installation).

After much searching I managed to find several resources that pointed me in the right direction (as most of the OpenNI links are dead these days?)

I fear I may have installed deprecated versions of everything, however I have been able to get images out of the RGB camera, see below:

[image]

Now,  as you can see the RGB image is very scrambled, and I am getting no depth data whatsoever.

(Note the green text at the bottom, perhaps this may be important, I dont know..)

It may also be worth noting that the on the windows machine I appear to be having some form of driver discrepancies on the camera, and audio, as aswell as no information on the depth camera (I am unsure if this is bundled with the normal camera) see below:

[image]

I also am only able to get this information from the camera if the device is plugged into a USB 3.0 port, if plugged into any of the 2.0 ports, I am hit with a `PrimeSense:(Device not connected)` error.

Hopefully someone else has overcome these issues and would be willing to help me with this solution, apologies if this question is not seen as off topic for stackoverflow, If someone can suggest a better place to post this, I will happily move it there (However I felt this may be a little too *specific* for a general ubuntu site)

Cheers.

Comment: Most probably you are using kinect for windows v2. Kinect for windows v2 requires usb 3 to run. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846191/usb3-controller-kinect-2/30847224#30847224 may help you if you face usb 3.0 compatibility problem with kinect for windows v2.

Comment: does kinect work fine in you windows OS?

Comment: Hi rafaf, I am not sure as I have not installed anything on the windows machine that would handle the kinect data. I will try installing open ni on the windows machine as well and see if that improves the situation. I will post results here.